# How to make generic function for validation which return error mesages?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you please tell me  How to make generic function for validation which return error messages?
Here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-j39p0

```
helperText={
          (errors.firstName &&
            errors.firstName.type === "required" &&
            "First name is required") ||
          (errors.firstName &&
            errors.firstName.type === "pattern" &&
            "Invalid user")
        }
```

instead of above `line` i want to create a function which return error message (`depending on type`) example it is type of `required` it shows me it is required .if it pattern error show invalid user.

Comment: You can refer this link for it: https://learnetto.com/blog/react-form-validation

Comment: What do you mean by `generic function`? If you want custom validation, just edit the `inputRef={register({ required: true, pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i })}`

Comment: @keikai where is my message ...!! how to show error message

Comment: @keikai like it is `required` and pattern is not matched

Comment: The error message is just showing on the textfield, the `register` is the very place you write your validations

Comment: @keikai I got it ..but I want to show error messages ..!!

Comment: What do you mean by `show` error messages? It shows NOW if you input invalid value

Comment: here is already show `inputRef={register({ required: true, pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i })}
` my validation but now I want to show error messages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207242/discussion-between-keikai-and-user944513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the method below, you can

1.put the validation process to common service files
2.make the input fields in your repo managed by single source constant,
3.reuse the error message as you want.

```js
const App = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => {};

  const validation = [
    { name: "required", value: true, message: "Input required" },
    { name: "pattern", value: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i, message: "Invalid input" }
  ];

  const validateItems = { name: "firstName", method: ["required", "pattern"] };

  function makeRegister(checkList) {
    let result = {};
    validation.forEach(item => {
      if (checkList.includes(item.name)) {
        result[item.name] = item.value;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

  function makeHelpText(unit, checkList) {
    console.log(unit);
    let result = "";
    checkList.forEach(name => {
      if (unit && unit.type === name) {
        return (result = validation.find(x => x.name === name).message);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
      <TextField
        inputRef={register(makeRegister(validateItems.method))}
        label="First name"
        variant="outlined"
        name={validateItems.name}
        required
        helperText={makeHelpText(
          errors[validateItems.name],
          validateItems.method
        )}
        error={errors.firstName ? true : false}
      />

      <Button color="primary" type="submit" variant="contained" fullWidth>
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Get Started]