# Using React to create a form, how could I get my err message to display on Submit (when the submit button is clicked)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React to create a form with two input text and would like to display an error message every time the user enters a non-numerical value as the age and clicks the submit button. The form apparently is doing most of what I want but it is not displaying the error message.

NB: I would love not to use the alert() syntax here if possible.

Thanks for your help.

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      age: null,
      errormessage: ''
    };
  }
  
 errorHandler = () => {
  let err = '';
  if (nam === "age") {
    if (val !="" && !Number(val)) {
      err = <strong>Your age must be a number</strong>;
    }
  }
  this.setState({errormessage: err});
 }
  
  myChangeHandler = (event) => {
    let nam = event.target.name;
    let val = event.target.value;
    this.setState({[nam]: val});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.errorHandler}>
      <h1>Hello {this.state.username} {this.state.age}</h1>
      <p>Enter your name:</p>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='username'
        onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
      />
      <p>Enter your age:</p>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='age'
        onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
      />
      <br/>
      <input 
        type='submit' 
      />
      {this.state.errormessage}
      </form>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make generic function for validation which return error mesages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60070467/how-to-make-generic-function-for-validation-which-return-error-mesages)

Comment: No it doesn't as It is not possible to test the suggested answer and I tried to implement it and was not getting the expected result. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your errorHandler you have two undefined variables, nam and val, (nam === "age") and (val !="" && !Number(val)). The nam and val variables only work inside the local scope of your myChangeHandler method. I would separate your onChange handlers into two as shown below to set the different inputs. Finally, you could use Number() on the state age to convert a string to a number, then you use the if statement to use isNaN() to see if the age is a number or not. When you try to use Number() on a string value with letters it will return Not a Number so you can check that using isNaN(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Here is the code in a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-brattain-doz7t

```
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     username: "",
     age: null,
     errormessage: ""
   };
  }

  errorHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let err = "";
    let newAge = Number(this.state.age);

    if (isNaN(newAge)) {
      err = <strong>Your age must be a number</strong>;
    }
    this.setState({ errormessage: err });
  };

  handleUserName = event => {
    this.setState({
      username: event.target.value
    });
  };

  handleMyAge = event => {
    this.setState({
      age: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.errorHandler}>
        <h1>
          Hello {this.state.username} {this.state.age}
        </h1>
    <p>Enter your name:</p>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="username"
      defaultValue=""
      onChange={this.handleUserName}
    />
    <p>Enter your age:</p>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="age"
      defaultValue=""
      onChange={this.handleMyAge}
    />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
    {this.state.errormessage}
  </form>
);
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I would like to know what you mean by this "let newAge = Number(this.state.age);"?

Comment: I was just creating a new variable. Since you are using a text input for your age, the value will be a string, for example, '16'. You will need to convert the string into a number if you only want a numbers for your age input. Then I save the possible 'number' in this variable to compare it or use it elsewhere in the code when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can show error message below `Age` field. It is conditional rendering. It will be rendered only when `errormessage` contains some value.

```
render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.errorHandler}>
      <h1>Hello {this.state.username} {this.state.age}</h1>
      <p>Enter your name:</p>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='username'
        onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
      />
      <p>Enter your age:</p>
      <input
        type='text'
        name='age'
        onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
      />
      <br/>
      {this.state.errormessage ?
       <div id="err">{this.state.errorMessage}</div>
       : null}
      <input 
        type='submit' 
      />
      {this.state.errormessage}
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

You can test it by checking if `div` with `id=err` is rendered.

Comment: thanks for helping but I'm still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your errorHander method. The nam and val variables in your onChangeHandler() are using **let** and therefore, its having local scope only. I'll suggest you to bring nam and age from your state in errorHandler.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MyForm extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     username: '',
     age: null,
     errormessage: ''
   };
 }

 myChangeHandler = (event) => {
   let nam = event.target.name;
   let val = event.target.value;
   this.setState({[nam]: val});
 }

errorHandler = () => {
 let err = '';
 let val = this.state.age
   if (val !="" && !Number(val)) {
     err = <strong>Your age must be a number</strong>;
 }
 this.setState({errormessage: err});
}

 render() {
   return (
     <form onSubmit={this.errorHandler}>
     <h1>Hello {this.state.username} {this.state.age}</h1>
     <p>Enter your name:</p>
     <input
       type='text'
       name='username'
       onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
     />
     <p>Enter your age:</p>
     <input
       type='text'
       name='age'
       onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
     />
     <br/>
     <input 
       type='submit' 
     />
     {this.state.errormessage}
     </form>
   );
 }
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to able to refine the answer given by @Springy to get the code below.

Thank you @Springy

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     username: "",
     age: null,
     errormessage: ""
   };
  }

  errorHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let err = "";
    let newAge = Number(this.state.age);
    if (isNaN(newAge)) {
      err = <strong>Your age must be a number</strong>;
    }
    this.setState({ errormessage: err });
  };

  handleUserAgeName = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]:event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.errorHandler}>
        <h1>
          Hello {this.state.username} {this.state.age}
        </h1>
    <p>Enter your name:</p>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="username"
      defaultValue=""
      onChange={this.handleUserAgeName}
    />
    <p>Enter your age:</p>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="age"
      defaultValue=""
      onChange={this.handleUserAgeName}
    />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
    {this.state.errormessage}
  </form>
);
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<MyForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```